# How to save a List of persistent objects bound to another objects with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a main Object called Menu, with a List of objects VoceMenu

```
public class Menu implements Serializable{
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="menu", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  
private List<VoceMenu> voceMenuList;
...
}
```

when I edit a object Menu and then I save it with

```
...
getCurrentSessionFactory().saveOrUpdate(menu);  
...
```

I can see that on the DB, the value of the fields of the object Menu are edited, the fields of the objects VoceMenu aren't.

Probably I miss something.

Comment: Try adding to the OneToMany mapping cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST

Comment: Also another thing to think about. Is `VoceMenu` something that needs to have it's own lifecycle? If you only ever use it at the same time as it's parent consider using `@ElementCollection`

Comment: Thank you. I tried using cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST  but it doesn't seems to work to me. I found this article, I followed his example  and it seems to work http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/

Answer (score 0):

Did you set Menu on VoceMenu object before persisting? Try the following:

```
Menu menu = new Menu();
VoceMenu voce = new VoceMenu();
voce.setMenu(menu);
voceMenuList.add(voce);

...
getCurrentSessionFactory().saveOrUpdate(menu);
```

Also, you need to add cascade = Cascade.PERSIST to make it happen:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="menu", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = Cascade.PERSIST)
```

Comment: Thank  for your help. The Menu obejct inside VoceMenu was ok.

Thank you. I tried using cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST  but it doesn't seems to work to me. I found this article, I followed his example  and it seems to work http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/